# How to attach a proc as variable name to a button created by a loop

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Help me through one of my problem where i seized my thinking to proceed further. 
I am creating a radiobutton within foreach loop.Also wanted to have a -command option different for each these buttons, since i am not sure how many buttons will be created(it always dynamic) i put it in a foreach loop.

Further, I am attaching a proc as a variable so whenever any of these radio button is clicked the function body of proc will execute, but this code doesn't functioning properly and throwing error when radiobutton is selected.
I think variables $elem and $w are not getting passed to proc

```
proc check_lib_name {} {
   global ENTRYfilename5 ENTRYfilename f mylist elem w
   cd $ENTRYfilename
   set dirnames [glob -type d *]
   set b 7
   set mylist {}
   foreach f $dirnames {
      set r 2
      lappend mylist $f
   }

   set w 0
   foreach elem $mylist {
      radiobutton .top.d.$elem -text $elem -command $elem.$w -value $elem.abc
      grid .top.d.$elem -row $b -column $r -sticky nsew
      incr b
      incr w
   }

   #### Proc attached with radiobuttons
   proc $elem.$w {} {
      global ENTRYfilename5 ENTRYfilename elem w
      cd $elem
      set rrpath [glob -type d *]
      puts $rrpath
      set del "/"
      set klpath [concat [string trim $ENTRYfilename][string trim $del][string trim  $elem][string trim $del][string trim $rrpath]]
      puts $klpath
      cd $klpath
      exec [myRun.sh]
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong: `exec [myRun.sh]` -- you probably want `exec myRun.sh`. With the code you have, Tcl will call the *Tcl proc* `myRun.sh`, and then use the *return value* of that proc as the argument to `exec`.

Answer (score 2):

After the foreach loop ran, the value of `$elem` and `$w` will be the last value they had, which also means you have only 1 proc created and this is for the last radio button.

I don't think it is a good idea to make 1 proc for each ration button. Use 1 generic proc that takes arguments.

```
...
radiobutton .top.d.$elem -text $elem -command [list radiofunction $elem $w] -value $elem.abc
...
```

then

```
proc radiofunction {elem w} {...}
```

`radiofunction` is only an example name.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, i gave a try with this method but it only allows to do a one time radiobutton selection, when i wanted to switch between radiobuttons it throws error saying directory doesn't exists.

Comment: @DanishSheikh This is probably a problem with the proc body. Where exactly do you get the error? Also using so many `global` looks suspicious.

Comment: I understand the problem is due to "cd" in my proc, i am moving finally to $klpath which is basically a path to a directory , if i reselect another radiobutton, it sets another value of $elem and from $klpath $elem is not reachable.
I think of using pushd at start of proc and popd after end of proc.
I did try to use exec [pushd $ENTRYfilename] but this doesn't seems to working.

Comment: @DanishSheikh Why not use absolute paths?

Comment: I can't use absolute paths since , $ENTRYfilename is a path entered by user through UI, it will be dynamic. i am just passing the entry box content to the script.

Comment: Okay, so i manage to fix it by again moving into the parent directory and this way i am not getting the error.